# MQTT javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, express, mqtt

si I have a problem with my simple expressjs API that takes an payload containing an id of computer and a command that will execute on targeted computer. API works, at least sending messages to mqtt server works but there is a problem with receiving them. On the 'onmessage' event listener there is a problem where the first run of this code works, but when i try to execute on the same pc anothr command or even the same command second time the code crashes and gives me this error:

```
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const client = mqtt.connect("serverip");

client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("[API]: Succesfully connected to the server");
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.put("/command", (req, res) => {
  const { hwid, command } = req.body;
  console.log(`PUT method request for: ${hwid}`);
  client.subscribe(hwid, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish(hwid, command);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send({ error: "Failed to publish command" });
    }
  });

  client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
    if (command == message.toString()) {
      return;
    } else {
      res.send({ hwid: topic, content: message.toString() });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I've tried deleting this if statement with command and message but I need this statement so i wont receive the same message as I sent to the server, I want just the response from the pc that i picked using hwid

Comment: Why do you have a function call in the QOS field of your client.subscribe() call??  I think part of your problem is that function call has to complete before the subscribe() function can be executed....so your publish() is happening before your subscribe()

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that the on message event was inside of app.put(), I moved in a little bit down and passed command variable and res object so I can send this and it works

Comment: Even with that sort of change the code will only ever work with a single inflight request, look at the example at the end of my answer for a version that works for multiple inflight messages.

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT client really doesn't work this way.

First you are leaking `client.on('message',...)` handlers. Every time the `put` handler is called it will add another version of the callback. Each version will hold on to it's local copy of the `res` object so will try to reply to already complete HTTP requests for ever subsequent message.

Trying to map a asynchronous protocol (MQTT) into a synchronous protocol (HTTP) requires a detailed understanding of the different models. It is possible but you need to keep a list of inflight requests by passing an I'd on the published message that is returned in the response so the right response can be linked to the right HTTP session.

There is an example in my project here:

https://github.com/hardillb/node-red-contrib-googlehome-web/blob/master/action-route.js#L41